# Where were the Valyria scenes in Game of Thrones filmed?

Tags: game-of-thrones, real-location

We have finally seen *Valyria* in season 5. Can anyone tell me where the *Valyria* scene was filmed?

Comment: Are you asking for the filming location or are you asking if Valyria represents a real place?

Comment: The "Old Valyria" location is either in Spain or Croatia: see https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20150513103729AAxEZuH and http://gameofthrones.wikia.com/wiki/Season_5

Comment: It's probably just CGI. Those aren't real ruins.

Answer (score 6):

The Valyria scene was filmed at [Toome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toome), County Antrim, Northern Ireland. Seems though the place went under drastic changes during post production. Only the bridge where Tyrion and Jorah were attacked is a real place, the rest of the ruins is just CGI.

To back this up here are sources:

[Game of Thrones Season 5: Episode #5 - The Stone Men of Valyria (HBO)](https://youtu.be/ei2K3sX8_JQ) video from the GameofThrones channel shows the place where filming took part. Though the real place is not revealed in this video, river and a ruined bridge gave something to start search with...

So some googling brought me to this [watchersonthewall](https://watchersonthewall.com/split-pillars-confirmed-meereen-game-of-thrones-filming-continues-toome-today/) post.

Now, here's an image from the watchersonthewall site. The tweet states that this bridge is in Toome.

[image: Old bridge in Toome]

Compare this view captured from the YouTube video.

[image: Old bridge in Toome]

Though the angle is different the resemblance is hard to not notice.

Comment: @Vishal If this solved your question, you can accept it by clicking the green checkmark on the left :-)